# How to change value by key in an php array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
array (
  'ID' => 'X485000CF',
  'TITLU' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxx,
  'APARTAMENTE' => 'Apartament',
  'GARS' => NULL,
  'VIL' => NULL,
  'SPA' => NULL,
  'INTRA' => NULL,
  'EXTRA' => NULL,
```

I want to change the value of the key `"APARTAMENTE"` in to `"Cas/vil"`

```
function timobil($str){
  $timobil1= array('APARTAMENTE' => 'Cas/vil');
  return strtr($str, $timobil1);
}
```

and print this in an XML document using

```
$identification->addChild('property_type', timobil($tip_proprietate));
```

Comment: Can you please clear what you want to do?

Comment: I have this script to export an xml with data extracted from database. i'm using   
while ($row_oferta = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_oferte))
echo '<pre>';
 var_export($row_oferta);
 echo '</pre>';
and i need to replace the values of the keys in the array. Example: 'APARTAMENTE' => 'Apartament',  in to 'APARTAMENTE' => 'Cas/vil',

Comment: but what is your problem exactly?

Comment: my script doesn't change the value of any key. I don't know how to do this

Comment: `strtr` used for **strings**, not for arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array=array (
 'ID' => 'X485000CF',
 'TITLU' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
 'APARTAMENTE' => 'Apartament',
 'GARS' => NULL,
 'VIL' => NULL,
 'SPA' => NULL,
 'INTRA' => NULL,
 'EXTRA' => NULL);

$array['APARTAMENTE']='Cas/vil';

print_r($array);
```

Now new array will be updated.